# Visual Studio 2010 can't delete data connection

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, server-explorer

I'm on Windows 7, using Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I created a database connection and its not being used any longer. I want to simply delete the connection.

I keep get an error saying: 
"The given key was not present in the dictionary."

There is another message I get when trying to create a connection to a SQL server: 
"Unable to add data connection. The given key was not present in the dictionary."

This is really annoying! I have done a google search and got some solutions, but they do not work.

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: FIXED THE PROBLEM!

Here's the answer:

On Windows 7 and perhaps Vista try renaming or deleting this file "DefaultView.SEView" in this folder C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ServerExplorer

Someone else said to remove the file from AppData\Local but that's just not right, it never worked and is why I posted this question here.

Comment: please take your comment above and add it as the answer to your question. This also helped me on my Visual Studio 2012 (which did not give the errors you described, but, simply locked up the UI with a spinning cursor, forcing me to use the Task Mgr to shut everything down). Thanks for posting it

Answer (score 0):

FIXED THE PROBLEM! Here's the answer: On Windows 7 and perhaps Vista, try renaming or deleting this file "DefaultView.SEView" in this folder C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ServerExplorer

Someone else said to remove the file from AppData\Local but that's just not right, it never worked and is why I posted this question here.